# Task execution concurrency

Tags: java, spring, task, job-scheduling

I have a web application configured to execute a job every 3 min.
since there is no need to change my libs or adding anyone i decided to use
spring native implementation of task executor.
So i configured my xml file this way:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="job" method="doJob" fixed-rate="#{jobConfig['fixedTime']}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

i omitt job bean definition and doJob method code 'cause unnecessary.

QUESTION:

Since doJob method will be triggered every 3 minutes in my case, 
how does SPRING handle the case doJob method takes more than fixed-rate time to execute??

Example:

- At time = 0

  - doJob is triggered
  - doJob takes 4 min to finish cause it makes some heavy db operation
- At time = 3 min

  - doJob should be triggered but previous execution has not yet terminated

how does spring handle this behaviour?
will the second execution be queued or skipped and lost forever until a new trigger execution?

Comment: roytuts.com/how-to-concurrently-execute-tasks-using-java-in-spring/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fixedRate task, for every iteration the executor checks if the number of currently running threads

- is less than `corePoolSize` then it creates a new thread and starts at the exact fixedRate time
- is greater than `corePoolSize` but less than maximum pool size then it creates a new thread and starts at the exact `fixedRate` time
- is equal to the maximum pool size then that execution is lost

For example, if you are using the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` the maximum pool size is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use `fixed delay` (takes miliseconds) and then it will wait 3 minutes AFTER the `doJob` method has finished.